# Jackson: Не удается десериализовать JSON Integer в Long

Tags: java, json, spring

Я пытаюсь десериализовать JSON в объект Product, но получаю ошибку:

```
{
"name": "Reflect T-shirt",
"description": "Cotton 100%",
"mediaFiles": [1], // Связь с изображением с ID 1
"category": 2,     // Связь с категорией с ID 1
"productPrices": [
    {
        "currency": 1, // Связь с валютой с ID 1
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "currency": 2, // Связь с валютой с ID 2
        "price": 120
    },
    {
        "currency": 3, // Связь с валютой с ID 3
        "price": 90
    }
]
```

}

```
2023-10-12 14:55:25.554  WARN 11952 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (through reference chain: com.citadelcult.citadelcult.models.Product["mediaFiles"])]
```

Я уже создал пользовательский десериализатор для поля mediaFiles, но он не работает.

Как мне десериализовать JSON Integer в Long?

```
public class MediaFileDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<MediaFile>> {
private final MediaFileRepository mediaFileRepository;

public MediaFileDeserializer(MediaFileRepository mediaFileRepository) {
    this.mediaFileRepository = mediaFileRepository;
}

@Override
public List<MediaFile> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    List<Long> mediaFileIds = jsonParser.readValueAs(ArrayList.class); // Предполагая, что mediaFiles передаются в виде массива ID
    List<MediaFile> mediaFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Long mediaFileId : mediaFileIds) {
        mediaFiles.add(mediaFileRepository.findById(mediaFileId).orElse(null));
    }

    return mediaFiles;
}
```

}

Класс Product:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MediaFileDeserializer.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_media",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "media_id"))
    private List<MediaFile> mediaFiles;

    private String linkName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<ProductPrice> productPrices;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
}
```

Версия Spring: 2.7.16